# Eloquent many-to-many-to-many - how to load distant relation easily

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables; users, groups and permissions

In models I have the relationships set as belongsToMany
in user model:

```
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Group');
}
```

in group model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}

public function permissions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Permission');
}
```

in permissions model:

```
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'id');
}
```

many users - to - many groups
many groups - to - many permissions

I'm trying to get all the permissions a user has, and have no clue what the code for it should look like. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
User::where('id', $id)->with(['groups.permissions' => function ($q) use (&$permissions) {
     $permissions = $q->get()->unique();
}])->first();

// then
$permissions; // collection of unique permissions of the user with id = $id
```

Comment: Still don't know how but it does work. Need to read deeper into the documentation.

Comment: super clever my friend

Comment: @PawelBieszczad You won't find it in the docs. That's just a trick to get what you need. Downside is that it will run 1 extra query to fetch it, but it's way easier than looping through the related collections, and it works even with deeper nested relations.

Comment: I have a similar question like that, but I'm kind of stuck, could you help me a bit, Jarek?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662699/laravel-eloquent-nesting

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Can you please give some info what is happening here?

Comment: @dbr This should do http://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this if you are eager loading...

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->with(['groups.permissions'])->first();
```

Comment: and how would i get the permissions?

$q = User::where('id', $id)->with(['groups.permissions'])->first();
            
dd($q->permission);

didnt display anything

Comment: `$q->groups[$index]->permissions`

Comment: I was trying to avoid looping, like a query to get all the permissions in an array or collection