# Laravel Get all realated models with scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been stuck a few days trying to get something that I think should be really simple but I'm not able to find the right solution,

I have the following Models (just printing the important methods)

**Order**
 id
 created_at

**OrderContent**
 id
 order_id

I have a scope in Order

```
scopeByRange($query,$d1,$d2){
  return $query->whereBetween('created_at',[$d1,$d2])
}
```

Which works perfectly, what I want to get is a collection with all the orderContents from that OrderScope

Something like

`$orderContents = Order::byRange($d1,$d2)->allOrderContents;`

So I don't have to do a bucle and merge the collections

Is there a way?

Comment: duplicate, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187043/eloquent-many-to-many-to-many#26187648

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JarekTkaczky for pointing me to the right direction,
my final function is the following one, is just do some extra calculations for reports

```
public static function byDateRange($d1,$d2){

    $orderContents = null;
    Order::byDateRange($d1,$d2)->with(['contents' => function($q) use(&$orderContents){
        $orderContents = $q->select('*',
                                DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity_sum'),
                                DB::raw('sum(total) as total_sum'))
                            ->groupBy('item_id')
                            ->orderBy('total_sum','DESC')
                            ->get()->unique();
    },'contents.item'])->get();

    return $orderContents;
}
```