# Laravel - Get records through over a relationship table

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm sorry about the title, I don't know how to explain it shortly.

I have 4 tables

```
threads
|id|title|

streams
|id|thread_id|text|

channels
|id|title|

channel_thread
|id|channel_id|thread_id|
```

channel may have many threads as seen `channel_thread`.

What is the best way to get all streams related to `channels` over `channel_thread`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187648/784588