# Retrieve nested relationships for a model instance in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My scenario is  this:

- I have a `Course` model
- Each `Course` can have many `CourseTopics`, through a `topics()` relationship
- Each `CourseTopic` can have many `Lessons`, through a `lessons()` relationship

Is there a compact way to retrieve and handle all the `Lesson`s associated with a single `Course` (for example, to list them, or to count their total number)?
My aim would be to have a very brief syntax to use in Blade templates; I don't want to involve logic (or at least, keep it to a bare minimum) or raw SQL queries into my template.

*What I've tried*:

```
$course->with("topics.lessons")
```

where `$course` is the current instance of the course in a template, doesn't work (gives to me *all* the courses with all their topics and lessons).

**EDIT**:

A solution is to define a `hasManyThrough()` relationship like:

```
$this->hasManyThrough("Lessons", "CourseTopics");
```

This solves the problem for a 2-level nested relationship. How about a 3-level instead?

Comment: there's no such relationship.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk That I know :) as stated, I was looking for a compact one-liner to obtain the same result (not necessarily a *single* instruction), for more than 2 levels of nesting

Comment: Yes, there is a way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187648/784588

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Thanks a lot. As a comment, I cannon upvote and accept your answer here but I've done it on the other thread

Comment: Sure, that's perfectly OK.