# Laravel Eloquent - accessing second level model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, object-relational-model

This question extends the example [Eloquent : Working With Pivot Tables](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) provided in the Laravel Documentation.

The relationship here is that a *User* has many *Role* objects that it can relate to. In this extension, each Role will relate to a number of Task objects, giving us a second level many-to-many relationship.

Using Eloquent ORM, what would be the neatest way of accessing the Tasks that a user relates to?

Specifically, the following method should return an array of task_ids

```
User::get_tasks($user_id)
```

Comment: For `ids` only use joins, in order to easy access the `Task` models, use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187648/784588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though @JosephSilber's answer looks great it unfortunately didn't work when I tested it, so here's something that worked on my installation:

```
public static function get_tasks($id){
    $tasks = static::with('roles.tasks')->find($id)->roles->lists('tasks');
    $collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    foreach($tasks as $roleTasks){
        $collection = $collection->merge($roleTasks);
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Personally I'd change the syntax a bit to this:

```
public function getTasks(){
    $this->load('roles.tasks');
    $tasks = $this->roles->lists('tasks');
    $collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    foreach($tasks as $roleTasks){
        $collection = $collection->merge($roleTasks);
    }
    return $collection;
}

User::find($user_id)->getTasks();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class User extends Eloquent {

   // ... relation methods...

    public function get_tasks($id)
    {
        $tasks = static::with('roles.tasks')->find($id)->roles->lists('tasks');

        return (new Collection(array_flatten($tasks)))->unique();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the neatest way is to use hasManyThrough relationship as follows:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function get_tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Tasks', 'Roles');
    }
}
```

You only need to modify `Tasks` and `Roles` to your named corresponding model. It shall return you a list of tasks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, `hasManyThrough` doesn't work for m-m relations.

Comment: Well, it depends. According to the description in the question, one user has many roles and one role has many tasks. In this case, they are all one-to-many relationships. `hasManyThrough` does the work. Otherwise, it does not.

Comment: You misread the question: *giving us a second level many-to-many relationship.*