# How to eager load multiply-nested relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to load a nested relation in Laravel.  My models are set up like this:

**Customer** "has many" projects

**Project** "has many" tasks

**Task** "has many" timeEntries

**TimeEntry** has a boolean column called "billed."

What I'd like to do, in eloquent, is select a customer with just its time entries, I don't need the projects and tasks in between.

I've thought of two solutions I don't really like:

1. Add a "customer_id" column into my time entries table and relate
   them directly
2. Use something like the following and then iterate
   through multiple for loops to get the time entries.

e.g.

```
Customer::where('id', '=', $customerId)
->with('projects.tasks.timeEntries')
->first();
```

That works, but really inelegant.  **Any idea how I can access timeEntries directly, using Customer**?  I tried chaining a couple "hasManyThrough" relationships in my customer model, but I couldn't find a way to do it.  It looks like that only goes two "levels deep" and I need to go three.

And *really* ideally, what I want to know is if any timeEntries for a certain customer have a "0" in the boolean "billed" column.  If there's a way to get that out of my eloquent query, I don't even need the timeEntries themselves.  Any thoughts on how to achieve either of those objectives?

Comment: This is how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187648/784588

Comment: Have you tried simply JOINing the related tables and skipping Eloquent's eager loading entirely?

Comment: Ah ok, Jarek's way worked fine. Thanks--never would have come up with that.

Comment: @timmyc yep, it works. There's downside, but it's soooo much easier than loops. Upvote the linked answer then :)