# grabbing a combined list of a Laravel relationship's relationship

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm building a roles/permissions system for my Laravel app and I'd like the user model to have a `permissions` relationship that gets all the Permission models its Role models give it access to.

Unfortunately, Laravel's `hasManyThrough` doesn't appear to function on `belongsToMany` relationships.

Is there a way to easily get a Collection that contains all of the user's several roles' several permissions without something clunky like a `foreach1` loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187648/784588

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eloquent many-to-many-to-many - how to load distant relation easily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187043/eloquent-many-to-many-to-many-how-to-load-distant-relation-easily)