# Laravel Eloquent nesting

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to return nested JSON response, need to connect multiple tables, but for now, I'm just trying with 3, the levels can go deeper. My models are following:

Update #1:

```
class Sport extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'sportovi';

protected $fillable = ['id', 'sport_eng'];

public $timestamps = false;

public function liga(){
    return $this->hasMany('League', 'sport_id');
}
}

class League extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'lige';

protected $fillable = ['league_id', 'liga', 'sport_id'];

public $timestamps = true;

public function mec(){
    return $this->hasMany('Match', 'match_id');
}

}

class Match extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'mecevi';

protected $fillable = ['match_id', 'home', 'away', 'kotime', 'day', 'kolo', 'sport_id', 'league_id', 'date', 'long_id'];

public $timestamps = false;

public function liga(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Match', 'league_id');
}

}
```

If I do:

```
$sportovi = Sport::with('liga')->get(); 
return $sportovi;
```

everything is normal, children of "lige" are nested where they should be, as shown on the link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjQgj.jpg), but, if I try to add the Match, like this:

```
$mecevi = Sport::with('liga.mec')->get();
```

I get a "mec" node, which is an empty array, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3wj2.jpg), instead going one level deeper, like in the previous example.

I've also tried making multiple with() conditions which throws an error 
**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mec()**

Update: Still the same, `mec:[]`, empty array.

I'm using Laravel 4.2.

Comment: What happens if you do this: Leage::first()->mec; ?

Comment: Same thing as Sport::with('liga')->get();

Comment: From the first image, Why do you have both `id` and `leaque_id`? which column do you use for relationship between `League->Match` ?

Comment: Structure of `leagues` table is `[id], [league_id], [league_name], [sport_id]` , and I use `[league_id]` because it is predefined in the XML I have to work with, `[id]` is just an autoincrement.

Comment: So, I guess you might use `league_id` for relationship. I updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: It seems that either your tables are wrong/ this setup is incorrect or you simply don't have related matches - as simple as that. Show the tables with relevant fields and I can help you out then.

Comment: May I bother you on chat for few minutes? :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LwJceMkv

This is the structure I'm trying to achieve (with multiple leagues, matches and bets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, my table relations were off, after giving all the conditions, like
`return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` everything started working as it should. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want to get all the `matches` of `leagues`

The problem might be in the second parameter in `hasMany` function

```
public function mec(){
  return $this->hasMany('Match', 'league_id');
}
```

The second parameter need to be `foreign_key`

```
public function mec(){
  return $this->hasMany('Match', 'match_id', 'league_id');
}
```

source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many

Comment: Something like that, I want all the matches, of all the leagues, of all the sports, so the hierarchy is sports->leagues->matches. At it can go lower, because every match has group of outcomes, and so on, and so forth.
I tried switching from `'league_id'` to `'match_id'`, but nothing happens, in the generated JSON, mec is still just `mec:[]`

Comment: What I'm actually doing, is retrieving the data in the same structure it came in the first place, in the beginning, I'm parsing this large XML file, writing values in the DB, and now I'm retrieving it as JSON, and it's required to have this tree-like structure, because of recursion, generating html from each and every node. Is it possible to the same thing with Laravel's Query Builder? It doesn't have to be done with Eloquent.

Comment: It should be done with Eloquent. I just updated my answer. It seems you might use `leaque_id` in `League` model  for relationship.

Comment: I have changed the relationship `mec` in the `League` model as you suggested, but `$mecevi = Sport::with('liga.mec')->get();` still returns the same thing, empty `mec:[]`.

Comment: Your example is wrong. These keys are `FK` on the matches table, then `PK` on the leages table.