# How to get posts of people I am following in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `User` model, a `Post` model.

In my `User` model, I have the following:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}


public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id')->withTimestamps();
}


public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

So basically, `$user->following` gives me a collection of users I am following and `$user->posts` gives me the collection of posts. I want to do this:

```
$posts = [];
$user->following->each(function($f) use($posts) {
   $posts[] = $f->posts;
});
```

but more Eloquenty way, if that makes sense. Because I want to paginate the result after this. I was thinking of doing `hasManyThrough`, but cannot figure out how?

Comment: A user will have many posts and a user will have many followers. But there is no way I in which I can see a relationship between users and posts 'through' followers.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187043/eloquent-many-to-many-to-many-how-to-load-distant-relation-easily) is link to similar question with an answer.

I think you wan tot do something like this:

```
User::where('id', $id)->with(['following.posts' => function ($q) use (&$posts) {
    $posts= $q->get()->unique();
}])->first();
```